# Why are Icon-Buttons not centered?

Tags: user-interface, flutter

I'm working on a Flutter application and I can't figure out why my icon-buttons are not centered in the middle of the page.
I wrapped my code in a `Center()`

This is my page :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I08dJ.jpg

This is my code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class LogInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LogInScreenState createState() => new _LogInScreenState();
}

class _LogInScreenState extends State<LogInScreen> {
  String _email, _password;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              padding: (EdgeInsets.only(top: 50)),
              child: Text(
                "Sign In",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
                padding: (EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 35, right: 35)),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  new Form(
                      child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: new RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        child: const Text('Login'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])),
                ])),
            new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Text("Or login with"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
          new Center(
              child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new IconButton(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              new IconButton(
                icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          )),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

I removed the texts field so the code would fit.
I hope you can help me,
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Set the padding for IconButton to 0, like so:

```
IconButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  ...
)
```

Comment: Actually his answer was quite precise. By suppressing IconButton's padding, the icon will look like centered in parent's area.

Comment: The default padding on an icon button uses EdgeInsets.all() so it's already centered. This won't help in most situations.

Answer (score 15):

The solution for me is to put IconButton inside SizedBox.

```
SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: IconButton(
    icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.moneyBillWave),
    iconSize: 80,    
    onPressed: () {},
   ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 2):

A few changes :

- Add `shrinkWrap` true to your `ListView`

  ```
  ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    ...
  ```
- Add `mainAxisAlignment` MainAxisAlignment.center to your `Row`

  ```
  new Center(
            child: new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton( 
                ...
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Basically `Center()` widget only center the row itself not the widgets within the row.
To align children in your row use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center`for horizontal alignment and  `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center` for Vertical alignment see more [here](https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041)

so for your code it would be:

```
`  new Center(
          child: new Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
        children: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebookF),
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          new IconButton(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.google),
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ],
      )),`
```

Comment: This does not work. There is some problem when FontAwesomeIcons is used within an IconButton. If it is just Icon(), they get centered. The solution is to include padding: EdgeInsets.all(0) in IconButton.

Comment: Exactly as @chitgoks said. When combining Icons() and FontAwesomeIcons, some phones render the icons aligned to one side. Padding:EdgeInsets.all(x.0) where x.0 is not equal to 0.0 does not help either. Making the padding 0.0 for all solves the problem.

Comment: None of the solution worked for me, so I just used `Icon` instead of `IconButton` and it is centered. Like this: `Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                                      color: AppColors.OtpColor,)`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need `Center` the icon because the problem was the `Icon` it self. Maybe the icon design contained padding or margin. My problem is on back button:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.lightGreen,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back_ios,
    color: Colors.black,
    size: 15,
  ),
),
```

When i change to `Icons.arrow_back_ios_new`, it back to normal:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.lightGreen,
  child: Icon(
    Icons.arrow_back_ios_new,
    color: Colors.black,
    size: 15,
  ),
),
```

You need to find an icon that contained no padding/margin.

Comment: this is hardly a solution.