# Center items in column

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to create two items (Circle above text, centered horizontally) according to following image:

[image]

I have created following code:

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    IconButton(
      icon: const Icon(
        Icons.circle,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 40,
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    const Text(
      'text',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

However, the result is following:

[image]

I found out that the problem is with the `size` of `IconButton`. When I remove this line, the icon will be smaller (as expected) and the text below would be centered. It seems that when Icon size is increased, it is not increased from the central point of the icon (to the all directions evenly), but it is increased **to the right**. Can somebody help me with this? Is it possible to change size of the icon without interrupting `Text` centering? Or is there a way to center it as needed? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it is not always sufficient to add `padding: EdgeInsets.zero`. What you can do instead it to wrap the `IconButton` in a `SizedBox` of specified size.

The problem is that the IconButton is not aligned correctly. More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55422661/why-are-icon-buttons-not-centered)

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
        SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 50,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          const Text(
            'text',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.blue,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
         ),
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the column Axid is centered, but the `IconButton` causes the issue.

Try this:

```
Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // add this
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.circle,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 40,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            const Text(
              'text',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

the `IconButton` comes by default with initial padding, removing it will show them centered horizontally.